# MySQL: How to insert into a table and rewrite information

Tags: mysql

I have already written a table that pretty much looks like this:

```
Username  |   Password    | ListContents
snarky    |(not displayed)| Mow Lawn,Do Homework,Make breakfast
```

And I want to overwrite/add to the table's ListContents field when a user inputs new tasks. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Having multivalued column value is considered bad design as it makes updates very difficult. Best way to fix this is to normalize your table to take `Listcontents` into a separate table with a foreign key.

Comment: it's a good idea to normalise this table to at least 3rd normal form in order to get rid of repeating data, which is considered bad design. edit: looks like someone beat me to it! create a new table which has, for example, username and listContentID as a composite key, and then list contents as you have it here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to be done. Look here [MySQL UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Edit: you should seriously consider the comments to your post about normalizing your table

Comment: Or REPLACE, or INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to handle things if the row doesn't already exist.  As others have mentioned, storing lists in a single field is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanna concatenate the new input with the previous values in the ListContents field.

`UPDATE table SET ListContents = concat(ListContents, ",newInput") WHERE Username = "snarky"`

If you can't/do not want normalize the tables, i recommend you try a least to store the values in a `JSON` format.